# What is the Font used in Amazon Kindle Android?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What is the font used by Amazon Kindle in the image below?

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Droid Serif: http://www.droidfonts.com/info/droid-serif-fonts/

Comment: I found it was Caecillia http://www.fontyukle.net/en/1,caecilia